# Is there a way to make this code more efficient whitout o(n^2)

Tags: python-3.x, performance, coding-efficiency

The qustion is:
given the List of strings called "string_list" which contains:

```
string_list = ["darpa","da","arprpa"]
```

you need to make a new list, called my_list, that contains all the 3 length possible strings in each word of the string_list:

```
my_list = ['dar', 'arp', 'rpa', 'arp', 'rpr', 'prp', 'rpa']
```

```py
string_list = ["darpa","da","arprpa"]
new_list = []
for word in string_list:
    if len(word) >=3:
        i=0
        for char in word:
            if len(word[i:i+3]) == 3:
                new_list.append(word[i:i+3])
                i = i+1

print(new_list)
```

My question is:
1. did i solve it in the best efficient way? (i know its o(n^2))
2. Which code will be the most efficient and maybe the shortest for this given task.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it and omit if's if you only use words that are lenght 3 to begin with:

```
string_list = ["darpa","da","arprpa"]

# as list comp
k1 = [word[start:start+3] for word in string_list for start in range(len(word)-2)]

# written out
k2 = []
for word in string_list:
    lw = len(word)              
    for start in range(lw-2):  # eliminates words shorter then 3 automatically, 
                               # range(0) or less is valid but does not enter the loop
        k2.append(word[start:start+3])  # this also removes the manual counter

print(k1)         
print(k2)
```

Output (identical):

```
['dar', 'arp', 'rpa', 'arp', 'rpr', 'prp', 'rpa']
```

Comment: i thought about that solution as well, you didn't mention the value of "start", is it 0 like i did with my "i" counter?